# Is it a good practise to use RuntimeExceptions for Error Handling?

Tags: java, exception, runtimeexception

I need to process an array of Strings containing Integers (positive) as Strings and the String "POP".

When Integer, I need to push the integer to a stack of integers

When "POP", I need to remove the top most element.
At the end, I need to return the top most element.

If the stack is empty at any point of time during processing of the inputs or at the end of it, I need to return -1 (error). I do not need to do anything else if its an error.

I have implemented this by surrounding it with a try catch block as below:

```
try {
   //logic
}
catch (EmptyStackException) {
            return -1;
}
```

My question is, is it a good approach - throwing and catching RunTimeExceptions in scenarios as such? If not, what is the best practise?

Comment: If POP and stack.isEmpty() -> return -1

Comment: @assylias I get your point. But is there a reason not to be using the RunTimeException? For eg, if there are other operations too for example "+" which would add the two topmost elements - wouldn't it be easier to use the EmptyStackException?

Comment: if stack.size() >= 2? Generally speaking, using exceptions for control flow is not a good practice. It also the to be slower.

Answer (score 1):

The advantage of Throwable (Exception and Error) is that they contains additional information such as stack trace, error message, etc

For your scenario, I believe it is not necessary to add additional information such as "which part of code causes -1", "what is the cause of -1", "what is the detailed explanation for returning -1", etc

As such doing:

`if(stack.isEmpty()) { return -1 } else { // logic }`

would be sufficient